# Rails Check box on MySql stored as a null or zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my rails app I have a list of items (like a task list) and for each item there is a couple of check box to set parameters.

When I submit the form, the checked box are stored as zero and the unchecked as null on DB.

the question is: Is there a way to configure it? To store the data on a more traditional 0 or 1, because I think that storing null as false and 0 as true is a bit confusing, specially if another app (like a C app) needs to read the data.

Comment: What version of Rails are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that the attribute you are working with is `club_member` as in "are you a club_member?".

Note that in Ruby/Rails, the way it is working now, `if model.club_member` will return false if it is not checked (value is null or in Ruby, nil) and true if it is checked (value is 0).

On the whole, I would strongly recommend that instead of letting other applications (like a C app) directly at your data, you should instead build an API in Ruby/Rails to expose the data from your application to external entities. In this manner, you will better encapsulate your application's internals and you won't have to worry about things like this.

---

However, all that being said, here is your answer:

Use:

```
value="1"
```

...attribute in your checkbox HTML tags, and set the default value of the **boolean** attribute (in your migration) to 0.

Comment: Thank you! This resolved the issue (including the value=1) and setting default value on the migration to 0.

Comment: I am facing the same problem but I am using ExtJS form. I tried setting the default value to 0 ( in migration file) and value :1 to the checkbox component but the problem still persists. Any idea with extjs ?

Comment: @Rashmi I'm not familiar with ExtJS. I would recommend you setup two checkboxes, mark one and leave the other unmarked, and submit the form. In your controller, do a `raise params.inspect` at the beginning of your action so that you can see in the backtrace exactly what is coming through from the form to the app for each situation.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of potential reasons for this:

- Make sure that the column in the database is of type "boolean" in the migration
- Place a default on boolean values
- Use "check_box" on the form, not "check_box_tag"
- Some versions of Rails had this behaviour on generated scaffolds, I think setting the default fixed this, but I can't quite remember.

Comment: The column on db is set to true and I forced its default value to false. The null is gone, but now all values are zero! I am creating the check box on the fly using dynamic dom, maybe this is the issue.

Comment: Using it dynamically might still be OK.  I'd recommend doing it via standard Rails helpers first, then mimic the generated HTML in your DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

`value.to_i.zero?`

```
>> a=nil
=> nil
>> a.to_i.zero?
=> true
>> a=0
=> 0
>> a.to_i.zero?
=> true
>> a=3
=> 3
>> a.to_i.zero?
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

From the rails documentation:

An object is blank if it’s false, empty, or a whitespace string. For example, “”, “ “, nil, [], and {} are blank.

This simplifies:
  if !address.nil? && !address.empty?

…to:
  if !address.blank?